# How to open browser with extension already enabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I get the following code to open chromedriver with extension but this extension is disabled, Is there any way that when chrome is launched, it launch with enabled extension -

```
 chrome_options = Options()
 chrome_options.add_extension('C:\Python\extension_3_19_6_0.crx')

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
 driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. My question is the extension of the same question you are referring to. I'am asking that when extension is added in chromedriver it's not activated and i'm unable to find anywaythat chromedriver opens up with activated extension

Comment: I think this question should be instead posted --> https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ I looked on a similar question:
questions/30312/enable-flash-player-on-chrome-62-while-running-selenium-test

Comment: @Xsi This question is fine here. It's more programming related than SQA related anyway.